# Animating text within the input field

Tags: javascript, css, animation, console

I am developing a JavaScript console, in which when user types a command and presses enter, the console does it.

One thing I was not able to figure out is how can one animate text in an `input` field. The `input` field will already have a value in itself, which I want to animate.

I can animate text with CSS animations for normal text, but that does not seem to work for `input`. Please check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bv9onx6x/) for the CSS text animation. If there were a way to animate text in input with CSS, it would be preferable.

Thus, could someone hint or suggest me any ways on how to achieve what I want?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I have come up with a javascript logic which animates a particular text inside an input text field. Hope this answers your question.

```
var value = "Typing animation";
value.split("").forEach(function(elem, index){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $("input[type='text']").val($("input[type='text']").val()+elem);
}, index* 750); 
$("input[type=text]").focus();
});
```

Check following fiddle.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bv9onx6x/19/)

Comment: Not really javascript logic, more JQuery...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with an overlay over your input, and fill the actual text of the input after the animation finishes with some java script.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="Some text"></input>
    <span>Some text</span>
</div>

div{position:relative;}
span { 
    ...your h1 stuff here...
    position:absolute;
    left:2px;
}
input {font: bold 200% Consolas, Monaco, monospace;}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think you're probably looking for something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/bv9onx6x/16/

That is going to listen for the onkeypress and then the JavaScript will fire and set the inner html of the new `<h1>` to whatever value is in the textbox.